# The most effective way of sprite(frame) animation in Monotouch

Tags: ios, animation, xamarin.ios, sprite

I would like to know the best(high performance / FPS) way of doing sprite (frame) animations in a MonoTouch project.

I'm doing this very effectively in Android by decoding whole sprite image, clip it at desired sizes and display frames at desired pace.

So, what's the most effective way of doing this in Monotouch, in terms of FPS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using [MonoGame](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame)?

The SpriteBatch class works well for us.  It is OpenTK/OpenGL underneath, so you could repurpose it for your needs if you don't want to use full MonoGame.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what are the demands that you have for your sprites.

If your requirements fall in the scope of what CoreAnimation can do, you can just your image into a UIView and use CoreAnimation to animate the view.

If you need more control, MonoGame provides a more comprehensive set of primitives for dealing with sprites.